# change data in specific ticket in JSON file

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

I'm using react the node-js and I have json file with saved data about tickets.
I need to change data of specific ticket by ticket_id

I have some experience with mySql, and what I'm looking for is something equivalent to:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN
WHERE [condition];
```

I can't find specific helpful information regarding that.

my target is to add "likes" features such that users can click like and it updates the same ticket in the json file.
*the json file may not contains any field of likes, so if not, need to add this field

Thanks.

Comment: please provide your code attempts

Comment: So this question is about modifying a file, not a row in MySQL? Or are you asking about the JSON data type in MySQL?

Comment: I want to modify a file. my JSON file is the DB is the program and save all the data. the idea is when someone clicks "like" it will modify the the actual ticket, identifing by ticket id.

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON object in your MySQL table is in a column with a TEXT data datatype, you need to read it, modify it in your js program, and then rewrite it.  In MySQL terms this looks like

```
  START TRANSACTION;
  SELECT json_tix FROM table_name WHERE ticket_id = ? FOR UPDATE;
  /* JSON.parse() the json_tix text string     */
  /* update the object as you need             */
  /* JSON.stringify() the updated object       */
  UPDATE table_name SET json_tix = ? WHERE ticket_id = ?;
  COMMIT;
```

The transaction stuff is `START TRANSACTION`, `... FOR UPDATE`, and `COMMIT`. A transaction will prevent a race condition if two instances of your javascript code attempt to update the same row at the same time.

Comment: its not inside MySQL. I have -no- MySql. it was just to say that im looking for the equivalent. I want to modify a file. my JSON file is the DB is the program and save all the data. the idea is when someone clicks "like" it will modify the the actual ticket, identifing by ticket id.